# poor performance of rpcProxy based with netty

Tags: performance, netty

I designed the rpc structure named tinywhale, which is is used for communication between providers and consumers. Below are the details for the consumer to invoke provider:

Below code is used to create the proxy to invoke provider interface:

```
public class xxxService {

@Autowired
private TinyWhaleProxy rpcProxy;

private HelloService helloService;

public String invoke(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    if (helloService == null) {
        helloService = rpcProxy.create(HelloService.class);
    }
    String result = helloService.hello(message);
    return result;
}
}
```

Below code is the TinyWhaleProxy.create method to create proxy for the consumer, from the code you can see that I use cglib's proxy to create the Proxy instance. Then in the callback method, I create a new NettyClient to sendRequest to NettyServer to get the invoke response.:

```
 public <T> T create(Class<?> interfaceClass) {
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
            NettyRequest request = new NettyRequest();
            request.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            request.setClassName(method.getDeclaringClass().getName());
            request.setMethodName(method.getName());
            request.setParameterTypes(method.getParameterTypes());
            request.setParameterValues(args);
            NettyMessage nettyMessage = new NettyMessage();
            nettyMessage.setType(MessageType.SERVICE_REQ.value());
            nettyMessage.setBody(request);
            if (TinyWhaleProxy.this.serviceDiscovery != null) {
                TinyWhaleProxy.this.serverAddress = TinyWhaleProxy.this.serviceDiscovery.discover();
            }

            String[] array = TinyWhaleProxy.this.serverAddress.split(":");
            String host = array[0];
            int port = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
            NettyClient client = new NettyClient(host, port);
            NettyMessage nettyResponse = client.send(nettyMessage);
            return nettyResponse != null ? JSON.toJSONString(nettyResponse.getBody()) : null;
        }
    });
    enhancer.setInterfaces(new Class[]{interfaceClass});
    T cglibProxy = enhancer.create();
    return cglibProxy;
}
```

Below code is the NettyClient and its send method, you can see that I used the ClientHandler to handle message sending:

```
public class NettyClient {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyClient.class);
private ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
private EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
private Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
private Channel clientChannel;

public NettyClient(String host, int port) throws InterruptedException {
    ((Bootstrap)((Bootstrap)((Bootstrap)this.bootstrap.group(this.group)).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)).option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)).handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
            channel.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(5, 5, 12));
            channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageDecoder", new NettyMessageDecoder(1048576, 4, 4));
            channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageEncoder", new NettyMessageEncoder());
            channel.pipeline().addLast("heartBeatHandler", new HeartBeatRequestHandler());
            channel.pipeline().addLast("clientHandler", NettyClient.this.clientHandler);
            channel.pipeline().addLast("loginAuthHandler", new LoginAuthRequestHandler());
        }
    });
    ChannelFuture channelFuture = this.bootstrap.connect(host, port);
    channelFuture.addListener((future) -> {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            logger.info("客户端[" + channelFuture.channel().localAddress().toString() + "]已连接...");
            this.clientChannel = channelFuture.channel();
        } else {
            logger.info("客户端[" + channelFuture.channel().localAddress().toString() + "]连接失败，重新连接中...");
            future.channel().close();
            this.bootstrap.connect(host, port);
        }

    });
    channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().addListener((cfl) -> {
        this.close();
        logger.info("客户端[" + channelFuture.channel().localAddress().toString() + "]已断开...");
    });
}

private void close() {
    if (this.clientChannel != null) {
        this.clientChannel.close();
    }

    if (this.group != null) {
        this.group.shutdownGracefully();
    }

}

public NettyMessage send(NettyMessage message) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ChannelPromise promise = this.clientHandler.sendMessage(message);
    promise.await(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return this.clientHandler.getResponse();
}
```

Below code is the detail of sending message from NettyClient to NettyServer:

```
public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientHandler.class);
private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;
private ChannelPromise promise;
private NettyMessage response;

public ClientHandler() {
}

public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelActive(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    NettyMessage message = (NettyMessage)msg;
    if (message != null && message.getType() == MessageType.SERVICE_RESP.value()) {
        this.response = message;
        this.promise.setSuccess();
    } else {
        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    }

}

public synchronized ChannelPromise sendMessage(Object message) {
    while(this.ctx == null) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1L);
            logger.error("等待ChannelHandlerContext实例化");
        } catch (InterruptedException var3) {
            logger.error("等待ChannelHandlerContext实例化过程中出错", var3);
        }
    }

    this.promise = this.ctx.newPromise();
    this.ctx.writeAndFlush(message);
    return this.promise;
}

public NettyMessage getResponse() {
    return this.response;
}
}
```

All works that ok for me when I start a benchmark:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class ProxyBenchmark {
private TinyWhaleProxy rpcProxy;

private ServiceDiscovery serviceDiscovery;


private HelloService helloService;

@Setup
public void init() {

    serviceDiscovery = new ServiceDiscovery("127.0.0.1:2181");

    rpcProxy = new TinyWhaleProxy();
    rpcProxy.setServiceDiscovery(serviceDiscovery);

    helloService = rpcProxy.create(HelloService.class);
}

@Benchmark
@GroupThreads(4)
public String test() {
    String result = helloService.hello("sdfsdfsdf");
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(ProxyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .forks(1)
            .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
}
}
```

And the benchmark result:

```
Warmup Iteration   2: 121.743 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   3: 103.496 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   4: 125.844 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   5: 179.424 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   6: 120.635 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   7: 86.545 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   8: 184.926 ops/s
Warmup Iteration   9: 136.450 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  10: 169.146 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  11: 161.570 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  12: 157.327 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  13: 137.892 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  14: 120.632 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  15: 191.016 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  16: 183.634 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  17: 97.625 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  18: 145.066 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  19: 203.741 ops/s
Warmup Iteration  20: 111.741 ops/s
Iteration   1: 156.113 ops/s
Iteration   2: 203.618 ops/s
Iteration   3: 134.177 ops/s
Iteration   4: 121.404 ops/s
Iteration   5: 197.915 ops/s
Iteration   6: 199.298 ops/s
Iteration   7: 65.825 ops/s
Iteration   8: 184.359 ops/s
Iteration   9: 212.469 ops/s
Iteration  10: 139.439 ops/s
Iteration  11: 112.174 ops/s
Iteration  12: 199.004 ops/s
Iteration  13: 195.232 ops/s
Iteration  14: 90.157 ops/s
Iteration  15: 115.724 ops/s
Iteration  16: 191.738 ops/s
Iteration  17: 213.633 ops/s
Iteration  18: 159.058 ops/s
Iteration  19: 62.399 ops/s
Iteration  20: 165.608 ops/s
Result "com.tw.PerformanceBenchmark.test":
155.967 ±(99.9%) 42.118 ops/s [Average]
(min, avg, max) = (62.399, 155.967, 213.633), stdev = 48.503
CI (99.9%): [113.849, 198.085] (assumes normal distribution)
```

The performance is really poor, only 155 ops, that's what I can't believe. I checked the code and found that below code snap took a lot of time:

```
NettyClient client = new NettyClient(host, port);
```

Any advice on how to improve the performance? using pool?

**EDIT:**

Late in the day, I checked the NettyClient class and found that, I send message to server side and receive the server response, this process is in sync mode that caused poor performance. Then I tried to fix this process by using promise/future pool, but not help.

Then I checked other rpc structures and found that all of these structures handle this scenario in async mode.

So I think that my research is correct, sending message to server and receive the respon in async mode. But I don't come out a good solution. Any advice?

Comment: What is the purouse of your proxy? I have developed a similar project, where the proxy routed messages to another endpoint. I kept the connections created by the bootstrap and did not recreate them per request. The `NettyClient client = new NettyClient(host, port);` is a tcp connect per request. Syscalls are very expensive.

Comment: @RichardBurkhardt the proxy code above, only a create method inside it. It used cglib to build the provider instance and invoke it to get the result. So per your info, I think maybe I should start a NettyClient pool to manage?

Comment: Yes you should definitly work with open connections (Client pool). Be aware of connections that close transparently. Netty will not necessarily recognize it. It depends on OS settings. You should send Ping Pong Messages from time to time to check if a connection is closed or not.

Comment: Let me know if it worked. I would like to get a valid answer here, if possible?

Comment: @RichardBurkhardt Sorry, seems the client pool not work, the bad performance due to client's sendMessage method, need to fix it with future or promise, any advice?